# Preventing everything but a specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

I have a page which has a droppable element `a1`, as well as a specific element `a2` which is sortable. Files dropped into `a1` are read and deposited into a sortable list in `a2`. The upload and sortable scripts are not included in my code below as they are not relevant to the issue.

The problem is that if any file is dropped anywhere into other than `a1`, the browser will attempt to open the file for display in the browser. This is quite evident with image files..

I have tried to disable everything but `a1` with the following code, but this still does not appear to have worked, I'm still getting the unwanted redirect...

I've Googled my butt off here, but it seems there's a lot about *adding* drag and drop, but very little with respect to *preventing* drag and drop...

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here with the following code?

```
<div id="a1"></div>
<div id="a2"></div>
<script>
drop = $("not(#a1)");
drop.droppable("option",{disabled:true, tolerance:"pointer"});
drop.droppable("disable");
drop.on("drop",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `not(#a1)` is not a valid selector, and will return an empty set. You probably wanted to write `:not(#a1)` (with colon). Also, you might want to just override `drop` on `document`, and have bubbling handle it, rather than work on every single element.

Comment: Yes, I did want "`:not(#a1)`", but it seems that even applying this freezes the sub elements that get populated into `a2`... And i need these sub-elements within `a2` to be draggable and therefore sortable within `a2`...

Comment: Indeed. Which is why I suggest blocking just `document`, which will catch all the drops that were not caught before (by the handler on `#a1`).

Comment: I just tried: `$(document.on('drop', function(e) {e.preventDefault();)};` and while `a1` still works, `a2`'s sub-elements are still locked down, they've been rendered immobile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enough tinkering I managed to come up with a more suitable solution...

Seeing I'm only really focusing on the prevention of files being dropped into sortable area, I decided to focus on determining the nature of the item being dropped...

```
drop = $(".all-slides");
drop.on('dragover', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
drop.on('dragenter', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
                                            drop.on('drop', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    if(dt.types != null && (dt.types.indexOf ? dt.types.indexOf('Files') != -1 : dt.types.contains('application/x-moz-file'))) {
        alert('You cannot upload images here. \nIf you wish to upload files, \nclick on the "Upload Images" button.');
    }
});
```

Put simply, the drop event listens for any possibility of data transfer, and if there is no data transfer possible, we know it's a DOM element... Otherwise we know it's a file, and we throw the alert...

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vQWVP/) to make it work. Basically you can cancel the event with a handler on the document itself, without worrying about where the file was dropped:

```
$("#a1").on('drop', function() {
    // your logic here
    alert('dropped on a1!');
});

$(document).on('drop dragover', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

If you are using an older version of jQuery, you might have to replace the `on` function with `live`.

Comment: This code doesn't work for me either... Still does the unwanted redirect

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong jQuery selector for not.

Try this

```
drop = $("div").not("#a1");
```

Comment: Unfortunately this renders all the draggable and sortable elements in `a2` immovable... And I need those sub elements within a2 to be sortable and movable within `a2`...